# Inconsistency in Python Interface for Scaling and Applying Transform on Empty Object

Tags: python, interface, transforms, scale

In Blender 2.8.x, using the python interface one cannot `scale` an empty object and then apply the transform using `apply_tranform` similar to `mesh` objects. Does anyone know a way around this?

The issue can be produced as follows:

```py
bpy.ops.object.empty_add(type='PLAIN_AXES')
empty_obj_handle = D.objects['Empty']
# Pick a random scale
# The command below results in a scaled object
empty_obj_handle.scale = (0.1,0.1,0.1)
# Now applying the following command removes the scaling
bpy.ops.object.transform_apply(scale=True)
```

The `empty` object can still be scaled and the transform applied to the scaled object using the 'CTRL+A' + 'Scale' GUI hence the inconsistency.

Comment: Good remark/question!